# Thread safety for method that returns Mono based on mutable attribute in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In my Spring Boot application I have a component that is supposed to monitor the health status of another, external system. This component also offers a public method that reactive chains can subscribe to in order to wait for the external system to be up.

```
@Component
public class ExternalHealthChecker {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExternalHealthChecker.class);

  private final WebClient externalSystemWebClient = WebClient.builder().build(); // config omitted

  private volatile boolean isUp = true;
  private volatile CompletableFuture<String> completeWhenUp = new CompletableFuture<>();

  @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * ? * *")
  private void checkExternalSystemHealth() {
    webClient.get() //
        .uri("/health") //
        .retrieve() //
        .bodyToMono(Void.class) //
        .doOnError(this::handleHealthCheckError) //
        .doOnSuccess(nothing -> this.handleHealthCheckSuccess()) //
        .subscribe(); //
  }

  private void handleHealthCheckError(final Throwable error) {
    if (this.isUp) {
      LOG.error("External System is now DOWN. Health check failed: {}.", error.getMessage());
    }
    this.isUp = false;
  }

  private void handleHealthCheckSuccess() {
  // the status changed from down -> up, which has to complete the future that might be currently waited on  
  if (!this.isUp) {
      LOG.warn("External System is now UP again.");
      this.isUp = true;
      this.completeWhenUp.complete("UP");
      this.completeWhenUp = new CompletableFuture<>();
    }
  }


  public Mono<String> waitForExternalSystemUPStatus() {
    if (this.isUp) {
      LOG.info("External System is already UP!");
      return Mono.empty();
    } else {
      LOG.warn("External System is DOWN. Requesting process can now wait for UP status!");
      return Mono.fromFuture(completeWhenUp);
    }
  }
}
```

The method `waitForExternalSystemUPStatus` is public and may be called from many, different threads. The idea behind this is to provide some of the reactive flux chains in the application a method of pausing their processing until the external system is up. These chains cannot process their elements when the external system is down.

```
someFlux
  .doOnNext(record -> LOG.info("Next element")
  .delayUntil(record -> externalHealthChecker.waitForExternalSystemUPStatus())
  ... // starting processing
```

The issue here is that I can't really wrap my head around which part of this code needs to be synchronised. I think there should not be an issue with multiple threads calling `waitForExternalSystemUPStatus`at the same time, as this method is not writing anything. So I feel like this method does not need to be synchronised. However, the method annotated with `@Scheduled` will also run on it's own thread and will in-fact write the value of `isUp` and also potentially change the reference of `completeWhenUp`to a new, uncompleted future instance. I have marked these two mutable attributes with `volatile`because from reading about this keyword in Java it feels to me like it would help with guaranteeing that the threads reading these two values see the latest value. However, I am unsure if I also need to add `synchronized` keywords to part of the code. I am also unsure if the synchronized keyword plays well with reactor code, I have a hard time finding information on this. Maybe there is also a way of providing the functionality of the `ExternalHealthChecker`in a more complete, reactive way, but I cannot think of any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd strongly advise against this approach. The problem with threaded code like this is it becomes immensely difficult to follow & reason about. I think you'd *at least* need to synchronise the parts of `handleHealthCheckSuccess()` and `waitForExternalSystemUPStatus()` that reference your `completeWhenUp` field otherwise you could have a race hazard on your hands (only one writes to it, but it might be read out-of-order after that write) - but there could well be something else I'm missing, and if so it may show as one of these annoying "one in a million" type bugs that's almost impossible to pin down.

There should be a much more reliable & simple way of achieving this though. Instead of using the Spring scheduler, I'd create a flux when your `ExternalHealthChecker` component is created as follows:

```
healthCheckStream = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
        .flatMap(i ->
                webClient.get().uri("/health")
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .map(s -> true)
                        .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just(false)))
        .cache(1);
```

...where `healthCheckStream` is a field of type `Flux<Boolean>`. (Note it doesn't need to be volatile, as you'll never replace it so cross-thread worries don't apply - it's the same stream that will be updated with different results every 10 minutes based on the healthcheck status, whatever thread you'll access it from.)

This essentially creates a stream of healthcheck response values every 10 minutes, always caches the latest response, and turns it into a hot source. This means that the "nothing happens until you subscribe" doesn't apply in this case - the flux will start executing immediately, and any new subscribers that come in on any thread will always get the latest result, be that a pass or a fail. `handleHealthCheckSuccess()` and `handleHealthCheckError()`, `isUp`, and `completeWhenUp` are then all redundant, they can go - and then your `waitForExternalSystemUPStatus()` can just become a single line:

```
return healthCheckStream.filter(x -> x).next();
```

...then job done, you can call that from anywhere and you'll have a `Mono` that will only complete when the system is up.

Comment: Wow, that is such a nice solution! Just tried it, works like a charm and does exactly what I wanted without the thread issue headache. This is definitely they way better approach. Small thing: I think you have a typo on your filter function on the ``healthCheckStream``, it should return ``x`` and not just ``true``. In case other people want to use this solution (they should). Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Mercious Well spotted, I was bound to get at least one thing wrong without testing 